# How to debug a gtk application using gdb?

Tags: debugging, gdb, gtk, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to debug a gtk program by attaching it to gdb debugger but when I did the, gtk app freeze unless I execute next instruction or continue the program. It's annoying. I tried using ltrace but it is fill with gtk functions. How am I gonna debug this?